# Test if the first character is a number using awk

Tags: awk

How do I check if the first character of a string is a number using awk. I have tried below but i keep getting syntax error.

```
awk ' { if (substr($1,1,1) == [0-9] ) print $0 }' da.txt
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will suggest to use @hek2mgl solution. I have pointed out some of the problems.

Problems:

1. You should use regex inside `/..regex../`.
2. Use `~` instead of `==`.

Valid:

```
awk '{ if (substr($1,1,1) ~ /^[0-9]/ ) print $0 }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 9):

I would use a regex instead of `substr()`. This will do the trick:

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]/' da.txt
```

Note that I'm omitting the `print $0` since it is the default action in `awk`.

Comment: Or just `awk '/^[0-9]/' da.txt` since it's `$1`.